# Sort the records in sqlserver with date( get the "n" latest added records from the table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with a list of items. I add the records from the UI(asp.net webpage)
As n when I add the record, I also add the "created date" in a column with each record.
Now I want to get the list of the 5 latest items, depending on the date. What will the query be ?
my Created_date columns has entries in this format: 2012-09-21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to get the list of the 5 latest items, depending on the
>   date.

So you really want them in DESCending order.

```
  select top(5) *
    from tbl
order by created_date desc
```

> my Created_date columns has entries in this format: 2012-09-21

You may think that, but the entries in the database for DATETIME fields is an 8-byte structure, not some formatted string representation.  Unless that's a varchar column in which case you're in for some pain in the future.  At least the ordering still works since you're using a sortable format (yyyy-mm-dd).

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 5 [columns] from table_name order by Created_date [desc]
```

`order by Created_date` will order in ascending order by default (oldest first), if you want newest first, use `order by Created_date desc`

Comment: this is giving me the records created in the ascending order. (ie the records created first are being displayed)
i want an entry for records created latest( ie in the descending order)

Comment: then use `order by Created_date desc` as explained ;)